# Hadoop first example

Tags: hadoop

I am quite new to the Big Data idea & Hadoop so apologies for any obvious question.

Basically I having some problem when trying to run the Hadoop example like this:

```
jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar  pi 4 1000
Illegal option: h
```

Apparently I am using wrong usage but I have no idea what is it ?

Can someone please advise what am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Typically the syntax is: `hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 4 1000`

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I forgot to add hadoop.
I will mark Pual answer since your is a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy's comment is right on the money. Typically, the example executable jar is running in both local jvm and on cluster worker nodes. It should be launched with hadoop commmand: hadoop (or yarn in hadoop releases 2.0 and onwards) to ensure cluster config and related lib loaded properly. For a complete walkthrough, see the hadoop tutorial here for the release you have 1.2.1 : [hadoop 1.2.1 tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)

When got chance, you should checkout the latest hadoop release though. It's 2.6.0 right now.

Comment: The driver program in the jar does run on a local JVM, which then extracts out the mapper and reducer code and sends that to the worker nodes to be executed. The `hadoop` command line tool (instead of, say, `java jar`) is useful for automatically setting up the classpath with the local Hadoop jars so that the driver can do all of that.

Comment: Updated answer based on Jeremy's feedback. This excerption from java doc for job submission may help clarify the job submission internals: The job submission process involves:

Checking the input and output specifications of the job.
Computing the InputSplits for the job.
Setup the requisite accounting information for the DistributedCache of the job, if necessary.
Copying the job's jar and configuration to the map-reduce system directory on the distributed file-system.
Submitting the job to the JobTracker and optionally monitoring it's status.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it by prefixing 'hadoop'.

**hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 4 1000**